# How we can store the User utterance in a parameter without using @sys.any within the Dialog flow cx?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

In Dialog flow cx, I have created one page for Open question like **How Can I help you today..?**

Once End-user saying anything (Example:  I need reset my password), **I need to store that entire utterance into a parameter without using @sys.any entity.**

**What I tried** :
I have created few Intents like **Password and teams etc..** Example Password Reset like bellow

[image]

Here I created Entity SkillbasedRouting and give the reference for Intent as shown above image.

In route section I gave like this

[image]

**The Expectation is 2 things** :

1:  I want to store that user entire utterance in one parameter.

2:  Route the exact Intent(Matched Intent)

**Example Scenario**:

Bot: How Can I help you today?

User: Reset my password (Need to store this utterance in one parameter)

And it will go to Password route

Comment: Hi @R.Bunny, Have you checked this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547393/saving-user-utterance-in-a-parameter-during-no-match-intent-on-start-page) for storing the user utterances in a parameter ? Let me know if you are looking for this or not.

Comment: I already tried that link. But they are used @sys.any entity and first one using back end. But for me Within the Dialog flow I need to store that without using sys.any

Comment: Hello @DhirajSingh,  I already tried that link. But they are used sys.any entity and first one using back end. But for me Within the Dialog flow I need to store that without using sys.any

Comment: Hi @R.Bunny, you can try creating a [custom entity](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/entity-custom) to implement your requirements. Let me know if it satisfies your requirements or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/webhook).

The webhook can access the original text in the `text` field of the [WebhookRequest](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/WebhookRequest). A webhook could simply read the value from this field and set it in a session parameter using the `sessionInfo.parameters` field of the [WebhookResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/WebhookResponse)

Sometimes, a webhook is the only way to access information in Dialogflow CX. The confidence score or the intent name could be other cases where you would need a webhook.